# Zappa is not invoking the right Virtual env correctly while deploy

Tags: python, django, pyenv, zappa

I am trying to deploy a Django app with Zappa using. I have created virtualenv using pyenv.

Following commands confirms the correct virtualenv

```
▶ pyenv which zappa
/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/zappa/bin/zappa

▶ pyenv which python
/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/zappa/bin/python
```

But when I am trying to deploy the application using `zappa deploy dev` following error is thrown

```
▶ zappa deploy dev
(pip 18.1 (/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip>=20.1'), {'pip-tools'})
Calling deploy for stage dev..
Oh no! An error occurred! :(

==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2778, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 512, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 549, in dispatch_command
    self.deploy(self.vargs['zip'])
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 723, in deploy
    self.create_package()
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2264, in create_package
    disable_progress=self.disable_progress
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 627, in create_lambda_zip
    copytree(site_packages, temp_package_path, metadata=False, symlinks=False, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns(*excludes))
  File "/Users/****/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/envs/zappa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/utilities.py", line 54, in copytree
    lst = os.listdir(src)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/****/mydir/zappa/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages'

==============
```

You can see the line at which error is thrown is different where virtualenv is installed. I don't know why `Zappa deploy` is looking for the site-packages here.